# Chamar dataframes em Loops no R

Tags: r, loop

Tenho uma série de data frames, os quais irei trabalhar várias vezes em alguns laços.

O problema que eu encontro é que não consigo "chamá-los" corretamente para executar outras ações, comparações, etc.

O meu código:

```
list <- c("2","3","4","5","6","7","8")
for (x in list){
  name = as.data.frame(paste("europe_",x))
  species_Europe_WGS84 <- st_as_sf(name,coords= c("lon","lat"), crs=4326)#WGS84 (EPSG: 4326) 
  st_write(species_Europe_WGS84,paste("species_Europe", x, "_WGS84.shp", sep = ""), driver= "ESRI shapefile")
}
```

Pelo que já pude ver o comando paste não funciona para a chamada de objetos.

Tentativa de um exemplo minimamente replicável:

```
nome <- rep(LETTERS[1:10],10)
lat <- rnorm(100, mean = 30, sd =5)
long <- rnorm(100, mean = 80, sd =5)
sep <- rep(paste0("nome",1:5), 20)

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(nome, lat, long, sep))
list2env(split(df, df$sep), envir = .GlobalEnv)

list <-c(1,2,3,4,5)

for (i in list){
  ### chamar dataframe
  write.csv(paste0("nome",i),paste0("nome_",i,".csv"))
}
```

A opção por usar o loop é que haverá mais ações dentro do código, não será apenas no save.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A função `get` faz exatamente o que é necessário: ela entende que tu procura um objeto presente no workspace chamado `nome_i`, com este índice `i` variando. Veja um exemplo de como utilizá-la logo abaixo.

```
nome <- rep(LETTERS[1:10],10)
lat <- rnorm(100, mean = 30, sd =5)
long <- rnorm(100, mean = 80, sd =5)
sep <- rep(paste0("nome",1:5), 20)

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(nome, lat, long, sep))
list2env(split(df, df$sep), envir = .GlobalEnv)

lista <- c(1,2,3,4,5)

for (i in lista){

  ### chamar dataframe

  write.csv(x = get(paste0("nome", i)), 
            file = paste0("nome_",i,".csv"),
            row.names = FALSE,
            quote = FALSE)
}
```

Eu coloquei os argumento `row.names = FALSE` e `quote = FALSE` na função `write.csv` para que as linhas não fiquem numeradas e para que não apareçam aspas no arquivo final.

Uma observação final: eu não usei o nome `list` para salvar os números dos teus arquivos, pois este é o nome de um comando nativo do `R`. Por isso, preferi utilizar `lista` em seu lugar.